# Get specfic child, when click on map custom control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, addeventlistener

I have a `div`  and its THREE `span` `children`, By using `JQuery` when I `click` on `div` then using following `function` I am able identify that which `child` was `target` or `clicked`

```
$('.unitContainer').on('click','span',function(){
     $('.unitContainer').children('span').each(function () {
        $(this).css('color','white');
    });
    console.log($(this).text()); // "this" is the current element in the loop
    $(this).css('color','black'); // This line change attribute of targeted div
});
```

Now I want this event if that div will the custom control on Map.

I tried this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(unitControlDiv, 'click', function() {          
    $('.unitContainer').children('span').each(function () {
        $(this).css('color','white');
    });
    $(unitControlDiv).css('color','black');
});
```

And this:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(unitControlDiv, 'click', function() {         
    $('.unitContainer').children('span').each(function () {
        $(this).css('color','white');
    });
    $(this).css('color','black');
});
```

But both not working. What I do now to make it working?

**Update 1**

1 : Default Control
2 : My Control (Custom Control) (Div with 3 spans)
[image]

**Update 2**

This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/xvxw4/6/) get targeted `span` using `JQuery`

and

This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/y5v2Y/3/) (div on a map) didn't get work.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'div will the custom control'?

Comment: I mean that I add that div on map. There are some controls on map like `ZoomIn btn`, `ZoomOut Btn` 'Round Navigator' taht provided by Google Map. But I add this div manually  so i think it is a custom control. (i think so maybe am wrong)

Comment: @setec i updated with picture maybe it will more clear now

Comment: also updated `JSFiddle` demo for both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with mouse event target:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(unitControlDiv, 'click', function(evt) {

    $('.unitContainer').children('span').each(function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
    });

    //$(this).css('color', 'black');
    evt.target.setAttribute('style', 'color: black');
});
```

Example [at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5v2Y/8/).

**Update:** Change of attribute could be localized using, for example:

```
var innerText = evt.target.innerText;
if (innerText == 'mi' || innerText == 'km' || innerText == 'ft') {
    evt.target.setAttribute('style', 'color: black');
}
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/y5v2Y/9/).

Comment: it nice trick but also have problem when user clicks at corners :(

Comment: hmm that nice. i already use this trick `if(evt.target.getAttribute('style') === "color: white;") {` . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5kv5D/1/) how it may work.

```
var milesSpan = $('<span class="custom-button" id="mi">mi</span>');
var kmSpan = $('<span class="custom-button" id="km">km</span>');
var feetSpan = $('<span class="custom-button" id="feet">ft</span>');

var hi = function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id') + " clicked!");
};
milesSpan.click(hi);
kmSpan.click(hi);
feetSpan.click(hi);
```

Just replace 'hi' with your code, 'this' refers to span object;

Comment: by doing this I have to write three different `events`? I want that in single event like I did in JQuery

Comment: @BluAngel yes, what problem with that? Your code dont work because you are binding events indirectly to elements before elements was even attached to document. If you bind event directly like in this example, it will work. That means you have to bind it 3 times, to each button.

Comment: $('.unitContainer').on('click','span',function(){            $('.unitContainer').children('span').each(function () {});       }); A single click event for all three spans by apply on their parent?